# How to make string or int to be filled in every row using peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, api, orm, peewee

I have a query like this:

```
select id, 'Test' as test, 1 as number_test from table_x limit 10
```

result:

| id | test | number_test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 1 |
| 2 | Test | 1 |

How can I write (select) this in peewee and using .alias()

```
query = List.select(List.id, List.title, 'Test'.c.alias('test'),'1'.c.alias('ordering'))
```

This is not working.

Comment: Just saying *this is not working* is useless. What specifically is iy doing?  Is there an error message? If so what is the complete message? Does it run but produce incorrect results? If so exactly what is the results and exactly what is the expected results?  Something else then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Value`:

```
query = List.select(
  List.id, List.title,
  Value('Test').alias('test'),
  Value(1).alias('ordering'))
```